# Show factory variable in view without controller inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I currently have 1 factory that looks like this:

```
export function PageFactory() {
    var title = 'default';
    return { 
      title: function() { return title; },
      setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle }
    };
  }
```

In a controller i'm injecting the factory like:

```
constructor(private $scope:IMainScope, $rootScope, $window, $route, Page) {
    Page.setTitle('home');
}
```

Now i want to display the variable in the view, like `{{ Page.title }}` but this doesn't work, only if i inject the factory and point the title to an variable in the controller like:

```
constructor(private $scope:IMainScope, $rootScope, $window, $route, Page) {
    $scope.title = Page.setTitle('home');
}
```

And display the variable like: `{{ title }}` but i would like to be able to do this without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `$scope.Page = Page;` that should point to the factory and access it in view with `{{ Page.title }}`

Comment: Ye kind of defeats the purpose, but i guess it's the only way, thanks!

Comment: @LVDM By your description it seems to be what you want. Could you elaborate a bit more on your goal and I might be able to provide a better answer

Answer (score 0):

For class-based coding style controllerAs syntax is preferred. In current guidelines the use of `$scope` is limited to operations where it is indispensable (watchers and events).

Considering that `controllerAs` is `$ctrl`, it is

```
constructor(..., private Page) {}
```

and

```
{{ $ctrl.Page.title() }}
```

It always depends on the particular case if it is admissible to expose the whole service to view or not.